# SSH global $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, arch-linux, capistrano

When I'm logged in my **ArchLinux** server and type:

```
$echo $PATH
I get...
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

But when I'm NOT logged in and try:

```
ssh myyser@mysever 'echo $PATH'
i get..
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The PATH is correct in my /etc/profile but ssh seems to not load that.

Is there any way to fix it for all users/ssh sessions?

It does not happen when i using ubuntu

*Posting here as suggested by [Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914435/ssh-global-path)*

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/sh-startup-files-over-ssh

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bash as the default shell for the user, your `ssh` command starts a non-interactive non-login shell so it doesn't process `/etc/profile`. You will need to source that file in your script.

Comment: is there any other way? 

I'm asking because its working on ubuntu, maybe is an Archlinux problem...

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command via `ssh`, it does not start a login shell on the remote host.  The practical implications of this vary, but typically it means that shell initialization files that run *at login* will be ignored.  On the other hand, shell initialization files that for every shell instance will still be processed.

If you're using `bash`, this means that only your `.bashrc` file is used.  I often put something like this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
if [ ! "$RAN_PROFILE" ]; then
  . $HOME/.profile
fi
```

And in the bottom of my `.profile`:

```
RAN_PROFILE=1
export RAN_PROFILE
```

This ensures that I get `.profile` services even for non-login shells.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue adding the path into **/etc/environment**

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Don't know if this is a good practice, but is working.

Thank you!

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to 'accept' your own answer if it fixes the problem. You won't get rep, but it lets the system know that the problem is resolved, and later viewers may upvote it when it helps them.

Comment: sorry, but how can i mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The shell on your client expands the PATH variable, so you'll need to escape the dollar sign.</strike>

`foo$ ssh username@bar.example.com 'echo \$PATH'`

Comment: Not when it's inside single quotes. Your command will echo "$PATH" literally.

Comment: Well, that was a silly mistake to make.